# Differences between MemoryBlockStore and SPVBlockStore

Tags: blockchain, bitcoinj

What are differences between MemoryBlockStore and SPVBlockStore in bitcoinj?

Which should be used for downloading the blockchain and why?

Can I use same SPVChain format file for all wallets?

Answer (score 2):

***MemoryBlockStore*** keeps StoredBlocks in memory and it is used primarily for unit testing.

Whereas ***SPVBlockStore*** holds a limited number of block headers in a memory mapped ring buffer. With such a store, you may not be able to process very deep re-orgs and could be disconnected from the chain (requiring a replay), but as they are virtually unheard of this is not a significant risk.
You can find the reference document from the following link:

MemoryBlockStore
https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/store/MemoryBlockStore.html

SPVBlockStore
https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/store/SPVBlockStore.html